# Why does setHint result in a null pointer exception on

Tags: java, android

I did manage to publish my roman numeral converter application onto Google Play and I'm currently making updates to it. You can reference the app in this question I have asked here [How to set textView as method output on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815786/how-to-set-textview-as-method-output-in-andrioid)

I have replaced the original `setText` methods with `setHint` based on this question [How to clear a editText on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175398/how-to-clear-an-edittext-on-click).

However on my convert button listener when I've changed the try catch statements to `setHint`

Android Studio says it can result in a `NullPointerException`.

Here is my code for reference:

```
try {
    int integer = Integer.parseInt(intValue);
    if (integer > 0 && integer <= 4999) {
        numeralInput.setText(translator(integer));

    } else {
        numeralInput.setHint("Enter an integer from 1 to 4,999.");
    }

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    numeralInput.setHint("Invalid input try again.");
}
```

What can I do to change the hint without result in the exception?

Comment: I think you are talking about the android studio warning.. you can just disable it

Comment: `numeralInput` *can be* null because `findViewById` *can return* null. Unless you get an actual error, ignore the warning

Comment: where are you defining `numeralInput`?

Comment: Simple solution is to put an if statement to check to make sure numeralnput is not null and the warning will disappear.

Comment: @MuhammadAshraf I understand I can disable the warning but I want to understand it better before doing so.

Comment: @cricket_007 I know that I can just ignore the warning but thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Cory  Roy it's defined earlier in the program where I've defined the buttons and TextView.

Comment: @Sean McDonald Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Rave So it's done in the `onCreate()`? It's just I've never seen this warning before so I wonder if it's possible that you are declaring it conditionally.

Comment: @CoryRoy That can be a possibility, since this is the first time I've used hint in my program. I wanted to change the hints so I assumed that using setHint() method would work.